# Transpiling php 7 code snippet to 5.6

Tags: php

How can I transpile this code snippet from php7.0 to php 5.6 compatible. I know it doesn't have functionality of anonymous classes.

```
function app()
{
    return new class {
        public function version()
        {
            return '5.4';
        }
    }
};
```

It is suppose to work when I call app()->version().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class v{
  public function version(){return '5.4';}
}
function app()
{
   return new v();
}
```

It does not break call conversion `app()->version()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially run a class object similar to this:

```
class app {
    function version() {return '5.4';}
}
```

Allowing you to call it as;

```
echo (new app())->version();
```

<sup>*This has been tested and works in PHP versions `>= 5.5`*</sup>